# extract numbers from a *varchar* cell and do math with them in pure mysql

Tags: mysql

is it possible to extract numbers from a *varchar* cell, do math with them and update the cell with the result?

i.e.

- a cell in a column has the value "24a10 b"
- take the 24, the 10 and notice the b
- do 24*10 = 240
- subtract 1 if there was a b
- store 239 in that field (change the '24a10 b' to '239')
- do this with all the rows in the table

Comment: Why do you need it, and why do you need it in pure SQL?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible without stored procedures.

Comment: I want to learn more SQL, and was wondering if something like this is possible with only queries

Comment: Ofcourse it is possible as it will just need string manipulation and arithmetic operation.  But this is definitely not the design that anyone would recommend.  Did you try writing a query as you wanted to learn?

Comment: I was trying with something like:
select (select substring(column, 0, 2)from table) * (select substring(column, 3, 2) from table)

Comment: @Jan yes, I did read the question; assumed the issue being related to the string-to-number conversion @Flores I've to admit that I didn't test my expression - that was obviously too optimistic, sorry - surprisingly any of given CAST solutions here (including mine) didn't work on my MySQL DB; only the implicit conversion worked, e.g.  `select (1 *substring('24a10 b', 1, 2)) * (substring('24a10 b', 4, 2)) - (right('24a10 b', 1)='b');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is looking for similar stuff, the complete answer is something like:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET cell = (
CAST( SUBSTRING( cell, 1, 2 ) AS UNSIGNED )
*
CAST( SUBSTRING( cell, 4, 2 ) AS UNSIGNED ) 
-
(SUBSTRING( latitud, 7, 1 ) = 'b')  
)
WHERE 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on your example:

```
SELECT
  (col * SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, 'a', -1)) - (RIGHT(col, 1)='B')
FROM
  op
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2a08/1).

- `col` is your value `'24a10 b'`
- `SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, 'a', -1)` returns the part of the string at the right of the 'a', which is `'10 b'`
- the multiplication of `'24a10 b' * '10 b'` automatically cast the strings to integers `24*10`
- `RIGHT(col,1)='B'` is true (=1) if col ends with a b, false (0) otherwise

Comment: what does the -1 means in SUBSTRING_INDEX?

Comment: using -1 it returns everything to the right of the delimiter 'a', please see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index, of course it will work only if a single 'a' is present in the string, i edited my answe a little

Comment: and how to store 239 in that field (change the '24a10 b' to '239') and
do this with all the rows in the table?

Answer (score 1):

It can certainly be done, but SQL is designed around the axiom of atomic values (i.e., [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)).   Splitting a field is almost never necessary.  About the only time you will need to use it in a well-designed database is with dates where you might want to work with just the month or year of a date field.  While you certainly will find databases that some idiot designed which you're forced to work with that violate this core concept, its a bad idea to start out by trying to figure out how to work with these designs.

Additionally, your last step of "store in that cell 239" makes me think you're still looking at databases like they're spreadsheets.  They're not.  Another core component of a database is that the order of rows is not important.  Fields, on the other hand, are always related to other fields in the same row.  You might set the value of of one of the fields to be something where the ID field of that record is 239, but you will generally never care about the fact that a record is the 239th.

That said, here is a query that will do what you want:

Assumtion: the format of the field is "11a22 b".  That is, a two-digit number, followed by a letter, followed by another two-digit number, possibly followed by a space and the letter 'b'.

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(Value,1,2) AS INT) 
    * CAST(SUBSTRING(Value,3,2) AS INT) 
    + CASE RIGHT(Value,1) WHEN 'b' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Great explanation. And I think i didn't explain myself well about the saving; I want to store the 239 in the field where "24a10 b" was. In other words: I want to update all the row's 'value' field in the table with a new value generated based on the previous value.